# Jump Section; We seriously need them

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

We need a jump section. When you try to find a question, there is a list of them running up to 9,000 questions. However, it is frustrating to go through every page trying to find it. We should have jump section that allows us to "jump" to the page that is in range of the question I'm asking.

Comment: What's a jump section? Is it like a warp zone? If so, what is that?

Comment: @Shog9 Well, basically it lets you jump to a page. Like if you are on page 1, and you want to go directly to page 284, you can use botton. But we don't have that.

Comment: Oh, so you're talking about... Like a little entry-field that'd let you type in a page number and hit enter, upon which that page would load?

Comment: Exactly. Only in my mind I imagine it giving a list of pages.

Comment: For the time being, you can accomplish this by editing the URL: should end with `?page=n` where n is the number of the page you wish to jump to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be relatively meaningless as a feature on SE question lists because the  pages are numbered from the top down. "Page 284" is only relevant at a specific moment in time. In a day or two the content of that page will have partially migrated to page 287 and some to 286. Page jumps are only useful when the pages are numbered from the back-forward in the way answer threads on normal forums are where the newest content is at the end of the thread.

There is no way to meaningfully recall a specific page in a sliding group like SE questions. If you want to favorite specific questions you can do that with the favorite tool or your own bookmark system. Cluttering up the site with a tool to go to page 284 doesn't help much of anybody because it's not a meaningful delineation of any specific content.

As noted in comments, if you have some interest in this you can do it by editing the URL yourself. If you want a more convenient way write a javascript bookmarklet.

If you cant find something, use the (quite good) search tools.

Comment: Good point, the system works "backwards" than that of forums.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find a question on a particular topic, try looking in a particular [tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) (just click the tag name to go to that tag's questions).

If you don't know how the question is tagged, but know something else about it, review the [search options](https://english.stackexchange.com/search). For example, you can specify whether to search for words in the title or body, or whether to retrieve questions that already have an accepted answer.

Keep in mind, also, that on many pages and search results, you can choose how many results to view per page (in the URL, like https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq&pagesize=50, it's the `pagesize=50`, or find the 15/30/50 buttons at the bottom of the page) so if you find yourself clicking through many pages, viewing more per page can help.