# Navigating the 'Unanswered Questions' Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The Unanswered Questions queue is now 136 pages long, when viewed at the maximum setting of 50 questions per page. The link options at the base of page 1 of the queue make it very easy to jump to pages 2, 3, 4, 5, or 136 of the queue; and if you click the link for page 5, you gain easy access from the bottom of that page to pages 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, and 136 of the queue. Clicking the link for page 7 there fetches quick links at the bottom of that page for 1, 5, 6, 8, 9, and 136; and so on. And if you click the link for page 136, you'll get quick link to pages 1, 132, 133, 134, and 135.

This arrangement allows you to step through the entire Unanswered Questions queue—eventually—by clicking successive links. But if you want to see what's on page 70 of the queue (for example), the stepwise method is clearly unsatisfactory. The URL for page 1 of the Unanswered Questions queue is https://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered, which doesn't offer an obvious way to insert a different page number into the URL. But if you click the link for a page of the queue other than page 1, you'll find a more useful URL. The one for page 5 of the queue, for example, is https://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=5&tab=votes). Once there, you can replace the number of the page identified in the URL with the number of the page that you want to visit (such as 70—that is, https://english.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=70&tab=votes); double-clicking the altered URL will then take you straight to the desired page.

Here is my question: Is there a more direct way to accomplish this jump to a specified page of the queue, via a page search box or some other method that I'm not aware of? My approach works pretty well, but it does take two steps—clicking a link to a page other than page 1 of the queue, and then replacing the page number in the URL there with the desired page number and double-clicking the URL or pressing Enter/Return. A page search box would get me there in a single step.

Comment: The one you suggested, substituting the page number in the url address with a higher number is the only way I know how to skip (for example) thirty or more pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jump Section; We seriously need them](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1748/jump-section-we-seriously-need-them)

Comment: Moreover, I am pretty certain someone recently (as in last year)  asked the same thing but I could not find that question, perhaps it was hidden in the comments, or perhaps the question was self-deleted.

Answer (score 5):

There's another way of searching through the *unanswered* questions. By using the advanced search tips on the main site, I entered  the following criteria in the search box:

> answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no

This led me to this page

https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+duplicate%3Ano+closed%3Ano+

Currently, there are 4,852 *open* questions with *no* answers that's a **total of 98 pages** if one selects the fifty results per page option. The most upvoted question with 16 upvotes is

[What is the plural of the word "index"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/what-is-the-plural-of-the-word-index)

But it was merged with  [Plural of "index" – "indexes" or "indices"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/plural-of-index-indexes-or-indices)

Although the search items may need further tweaking, by clicking on the options available you can get very different results.

```
4,852 results       relevance   newest   votes   active
```

To narrow the results further still, add **views:900** in the search bar, and [the number of pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0%20duplicate%3Ano%20closed%3Ano%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20views%3A900) will reduce to a more mangeable four pages, twelve pages if one sets the limit to 15 questions per page.

Comment: Very useful information—thanks!

Comment: Posts like that one that was merged can be removed by adding `locked:no`.

Comment: @Laurel Perfect! I hadn't thought of a merged question being the same as a locked post.

Answer (score 4):

I edited a SEDE query aimed at finding unanswered question on Stack Overflow. This is the [original for SO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/370061/old-unanswered-questions). My version can be [found here](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/858158/questions-without-answers).

It takes four inputs (the may be changed under the *enter parameters* heading):

> start (lower bound for date when the question was posted, default early 2010)
>
> end (upper bound for date when the question was posted, default 2025, so there is no current upper bound unless the date is changed)
>
> minvote (lower bound for vote count, defaults is 0)
>
> minview (lower bound for views, default is 0)

The output is a list of questions (title of the question which serves as a link to the question), the view count and the score.

Note that the unanswered section on the main site also considers questions with only negative scored answers. This query only considers questions with no answers at all.

Comment: Thanks for revising the SO query for EL&U use!